# Open files in "rock&roll" mode

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm wondering what is going on with the file `open()` mode validation (Python2.7):

```
>>> with open('input.txt', 'illegal') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print line
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U', not 'illegal'

>>> with open('input.txt', 'rock&roll') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print line
... 
1

2

3
```

So, I cannot open the file in `illegal` mode, but I can open it in `rock&roll` mode. What mode is actually used for opening the file in this case?

Note that on python3 I cannot use both `illegal` and `rock&roll`:

```
>>> with open('input.txt', 'rock&roll') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print(line)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid mode: 'rock&roll'
>>> with open('input.txt', 'illegal') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print(line)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid mode: 'illegal'
```

And, this is confusing, why the behavior is different for python3.x?

Comment: Gave me a good laugh after reading mgilson's answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Python 2.x `open` function essentially delegates its work to the C library `fopen` function. On my system, the documentation for `fopen` contains:

> The argument `mode` points to a string beginning with one of the following sequences (Additional characters may follow these sequences.):

Your `ock&roll` is considered "additional characters".

In Python 3, the [allowed open modes are more restricted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) (essentially, only valid strings are permitted).

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say my guess is they simply added input validation to the function.

Comment: The Python 3 behaviour can be achieved on Python 2 with `from io import open`.

Answer (score 16):

The previous traceback explains it nicely:

> "ValueError: mode string must **begin with** one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U'"

"rock&roll" begins with `"r"`, so it's apparently legal.

Comment: Ok, but why the behavior is different for python3.x? This is what got me confused a bit.

Comment: @alecxe -- LOTS of things are different between python2.7 and python3.x ... The devs probably thought that it was stupid to accept "rock&roll" as a file mode even though the system's `fopen` allowed it, so they probably added some validation ahead of time.

Comment: The `io` system in Python 3 is a very different implementation than the legacy Python 2 one.  The new io system is also available on Python 2.7 (and introduced in 2.6).  You should see the Py3 behavior if you use `import io; io.open('input.txt', 'rock&roll')`.  More info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html